# NullPointerException on Autowired object inside implementation of abstract class

Tags: java, spring, design-patterns, abstract, autowired

I have a odd problem with my code.
I have implemented the `template method pattern` to provide different implementation of the same alghoritm.
So I have created the abstract class:

```
@Service
public abstract class ExcelRdi_Iupr_Sl {
    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    private static String PROPERTY_NAME_FILESYSTEM_EXCELPATH = "temporary.excelpath";
    private XSSFWorkbook workbook; 
    private XSSFCellStyle unlockedNumericStyle;
    private XSSFSheet sheet;

    /**
     * Create the excel file with the RDI,IUPR or SL
     * @param car
     * @param fileName
     * @return
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public final String retrieve(Car car, String fileName) throws Exception{
        writeInitialize();
        Map<Integer,Integer> defMap = firstTwoRow(car, sheet);
        elaboration(car, sheet, unlockedNumericStyle, defMap);
        return writeFile(car, fileName);
    }

    /**
     * Import the excel file with the RDI,IUPR or SL
     * @param file
     * @param car
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public final int update(MultipartFile file, Car car) throws Exception{
        String filePath = saveFile(file, car);
        readInitialize(filePath);
        return updateRdi(car, sheet);
    }

    /**
     * Save the imported file into file system inside a temporary folder
     * @param file
     * @param car
     * @return
     * @throws Exception
     */
    private String saveFile(MultipartFile multipartFile, Car car) throws Exception {
        String path = env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_FILESYSTEM_EXCELPATH) + File.separator + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());
        File file = new File (path+ File.separator + multipartFile.getOriginalFilename());
        file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        multipartFile.transferTo(file);
        return file.getAbsolutePath();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the object for the creating procedure
     */
    protected void writeInitialize(){
        //initialize class variable
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the object for the reading procedure
     * @param filePath
     * @throws Exception
     */
    protected void readInitialize(String filePath) throws Exception{
        //read ile and initialize class variable

    }

    /**
     * Write the created file inside the file system
     * @param car
     * @param fileName
     * @return
     * @throws Exception
     */
    private String writeFile(Car car, String fileName) throws Exception{        
        //write on file
    }

    /**
     * This excel creating method has to be implemented by the concrete class
     * @param car
     * @param sheet
     * @throws Exception
     */
    protected abstract Map<Integer,Integer> firstTwoRow(Car car, XSSFSheet sheet) throws Exception;

    /**
     * This excel creating method has to be implemented by the concrete class
     * @param car
     * @param sheet
     * @param defMap
     * @throws Exception
     */
    protected abstract void elaboration(Car car, XSSFSheet sheet, XSSFCellStyle unlockedNumericStyle, Map<Integer,Integer> defMap);

    /**
     * This excel import method has to be implemented by the concrete class
     * @param car
     * @param sheet
     * @return number of elaborated row
     * @throws Exception
     */
    protected abstract int updateRdi(Car car, XSSFSheet sheet) throws Exception;
}
```

One of the classes that extend the above class has this implementation:

```
@Component
public class ExcelRdi extends ExcelRdi_Iupr_Sl {
    @Autowired
    private RdiServices rdiServices;
    @Autowired
    private AcquisitionServices acquisitionServices;
    static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ExcelRdi.class);

    /**
     * Create the first two row of excel file
     */
    @Override
    protected Map<Integer,Integer> firstTwoRow(Car car, XSSFSheet sheet) throws Exception {
        //code
    }

    /**
     * Create the row with RDI for excel file
     */
    @Override
    protected void elaboration(Car car, XSSFSheet sheet, XSSFCellStyle unlockedNumericStyle, Map<Integer,Integer> defRdiMap) {
        //code
    }

    /**
     * Import the Excel file
     * @throws Exception 
     */
    @Override
    @Transactional(rollbackFor= Exception.class)
    protected int updateRdi(Car car, XSSFSheet sheet) throws Exception{
        //COde
    }
}
```

So from the services that recieves the request through the controller I have a simple switch:

```
@Autowired
private ExcelRdi excelRdi;
@Autowired
private ExcelIupr excelIupr;
@Autowired
private ExcelSl excelSl;

@Override
    public String getExcel(Car car, String type) throws Exception {
        String fileName = type + "$"+car.getFleet().getFleetName().getFleetName() +"$"+ car.getFleet().getApplication()+"$"+ car.getCarType().getIdCarType()+car.getId() +"$"+car.getIdCar()+".xlsx";                   
        switch (type){
        case "RDI": return excelRdi.retrieve(car, fileName);
        case "IUPR": return excelIupr.retrieve(car, fileName);
        case "SL": return excelSl.retrieve(car, fileName);
        default: throw new FileFormatException("You can create only RDI, SL or IUPR file!");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int importExcel(MultipartFile file, Car car, String type) throws Exception {
        //Check if the file has the correct name before import
        String fileName = type + "$"+car.getFleet().getFleetName().getFleetName() +"$"+ car.getFleet().getApplication()+"$"+ car.getCarType().getIdCarType()+car.getId() +"$"+car.getIdCar()+".xlsx";                   
        if (!file.getOriginalFilename().equals(fileName))
            throw new FileFormatException("The file is not for this car");
        switch (type){
        case "RDI": return excelRdi.update(file, car);
        case "IUPR": return excelIupr.update(file, car);
        case "SL": return excelSl.update(file, car);
        default: throw new FileFormatException("You can create only RDI, SL or IUPR file!");
        }

    }
```

So this is the problem:

1. If I make `protected` the `updateRdi` all work fine but `@Transactional` annotation needs public method otherwise it doesn't work
2. _If I make `public` the `updateRdi`I receive `nullPointerException` on `sheet` object of `firstTwoRow` and the same for the `env` variable.
   Do you know why I have this behavior and how I can fix that? Many thanks

Comment: Whether you make the updateRdi method public or not, Transactional won't apply, because you're calling this method from another method (update()) of the same bean. Spring transactions are proxy-based. You need to go through the proxy to have Spring start a transaction for you. https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/data-access.html#tx-decl-explained

Comment: Ok, I have to put updateRdi  inside another class... I'll try but maybe still the problem with nullPointerException

Comment: Remove `final` from the `update` method, it is also this method should be `@Transactional`. Or the service that contains the `switch` statement.

Comment: Regarding the null pointer issue: you shouldn't need `@Service` on the abstract base class, maybe that's what causing the problem (you only need `@Service` or `@Component` on the extending classes)

Comment: I removed `final` and added `@Transactional`, removed `@Services` from abstract classes but the nullPointerException still present

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue is that fact that your `receive` and `update` methods are marked `final`. Also if you observe your logging you will see a warning that a `final` method cannot be proxied.

What happens is, due to the fact that there are no interfaces, a class based proxy is going to be created. This proxy will add behavior to all `public` methods (like being `@Transactional` for instance). It does this by overriding the actual method, apply the advice and call the method on the non-proxied instance (which resided inside the proxy).

However due to the `final` nature this cannot happen and the method will be called on the proxy instead of the actual object inside the proxy. As the proxy is not a Spring bean all the `@Autowired` fields are `null` and hence your `NullPointerException`.

You can observe this behavior if you would put a breakpoint in your `update` method, You will see, in your debugger, that all instance fields are `null` and that the classname is something like `YOurClass$CgLibProxy`. There will also be a field `target` (if I recall correctly) which contains the actual Spring bean which has the dependencies injected.

The solution to your problem is actually pretty simple just remove `final` from your methods and it will work.

Comment: thanks, I got it. Removing final on both `retrieve` and `update` it works and also the `@Transaction` rollback in case of error. I used final to follow the correct access modifier of template method.